# Como funciona Password Grant Tokens no laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, oauth2, jwt

Eu quero desenvolver um aplicativo para consumir uma api rest e eu quero adicionar API KEY para validar a comunicação entre a aplicação cliente e o serviço(validação entre dispositivos), autenticação de aplicativo, sem ter que os usuários do aplicativo tenham que criar uma conta. Eu desejo fazer como o [TMDB](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/authentication#application-authentication), que gera chaves de api para desenvolvedores. Eu encontrei um projeto chamado [laravStart](https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart), nele foi implementado um módulo para desenvolvedores gerarem chaves para autenticação de clientes(entre aplicações - OAuth Clients) e tokens de acesso pessoal(Personal Access Tokens), exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como na imagem, eu criando um novo Client ele me solicita uma URL de retorno e eu não entendi como ela funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo: Eu registro um Client com nome Lojaz e url de retorno: https://lojaz.com/callback e obtenho uma chave:rV5CQQCF4gHGS29zqAUazBJPof9pS6ESvg7C2hAh.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O meu cliente, um aplicativo mobile ou o Postman, faz uma requisição a uma url, exemplo: https://lojaz.com/api/v1/produtos/1?key=rV5CQQCF4gHGS29zqAUazBJPof9pS6ESvg7C2hAh, o que ocorreria? Pois na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#password-grant-tokens) não explica este detalhe. Pois vou testar o [laravStart](https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart) no Postman e eu não estou sabendo preparar a requisição.

Answer (score 0):

Deixa eu ver se entendi o seu problema, você quer adicionar um método de autorização na sua API, assim liberando o acesso apenas para quem tem código de acesso que será passado como parâmetro da requisição para a sua API?

Caso seja isso que você queria fazer, o ideal seria criar um [middleware global](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#global-middleware) na sua aplicação Laravel.

Na middleware você pode fazer algo como:

```php
class CheckAccess
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $accessKey = $request->header('ACCESS_KEY');

        if ($accessKey === 'SUA_CHAVE_PRIVADA') {
            $next($request);
        } else {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou ter que melhorar minha pergunta, mas gostei da sua sugestão. Então, por exemplo, como no TMDB, eu quero que um usuário, do tipo desenvolvedor, possa criar chave de autenticação a nível de aplicativo e na url da requisição ser passada como parâmetro, exemplo: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key={api_key}

Comment: Mas eu gostei da sua sugestão.